# Which tense is appropriate? Simple or Perfect?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, perfect-aspect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

Consider the following two sentences:

1. Many buildings *were destroyed* in the Great Fire of 1666.
2. Many buildings *had been destroyed* in the Great Fire of 1666.

Which is appropriate, and why? I think both the sentences are right. 
Could someone please clarify?

Comment: Basically, a past perfect construction normally comes after a simple past sentence. It explains to the reader why a certain event happened. For instance, 1. "He **missed** the train because he **had woken up** late." 2. "He **woke up** late, so he **missed** the train"

Comment: Therefore, you need to tell us what you intend to write before and after your sentence. Both sentences are grammatically correct, if that's of any help.

Comment: You would use the second sentence if you were referring to the period following the Great Fire of London: it was necessary to rebuild because... The first sentence is just a statement of fact, valid at any time since 1666.